# no rule make object file

Tags: makefile, gnu

I need help, simply because I need help:

```
SRC=src/main.c
OBJ_PATH=bin

OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))
all:$(OBJ_PATH)/target.exe

$(OBJ_PATH)/target.exe: $(OBJ_PATH) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(OBJ_PATH)/target.exe


$(OBJ_PATH):
    mkdir -p bin  

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o:%.c
    mkdir -p bin
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_PATH)/*
```

when running it gives this:
make: *** No rule to make target 'bin/main.o', needed by 'bin/target.exe'.  Stop.

If I leave the objects in the same folder as the c files, it works.
I just need some help, maybe it is something simple that I am not seeing.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.c
```

When make wants to build a file `bin/main.o`.  It matches the target pattern `bin/%.o`, with a stem of `main` (the part that matches the `%`).  After replacing the prerequisite pattern `%.c` with `main`, make will try to find the prerequisite `main.c`.

But, that file doesn't exist and make has no idea how to create it.  So, that pattern doesn't match and make tries to find a different pattern that will build `bin/main.o`, but there isn't one, so make says there's no way to build  that target.

You need to make your pattern rule:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: src/%.c
```

so that when make replaces `%` in the prerequisite pattern it yields `src/main.c`, which exists, and this will work.

There are other problems with your makefile; for example this is a bad idea:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/target.exe: $(OBJ_PATH) $(OBJS)
```

You never(*) want to use a directory like `$(OBJ_PATH)` as a simple prerequisite.

Also, this:

```
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))
```

can be more easily written:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst src/%.c,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(SRC))
```

(*) There can indeed be very specific situations where having a directory as a prerequisite can be useful but they are rare and you shouldn't do it unless you fully understand why it's usually not what you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the **never** part of "You never want to have a target depend on a directory like `$(OBJ_PATH)`"? In http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#tldr, you use a `| $(DEPDIR)` order-only prerequisite very deliberately, so I do not understand the absoluteness of the **never** part. Do you mean **never** as in "**never** as ordinary prerequisite, but as order-only prerequisite depending on directories is fine"?

Comment: Yes, the latter.

Comment: I fixed it. I simply forgot the VPATH.